# Copy and paste text in jJavaScript

Tags: javascript, clipboard, copy-paste

I have the following question: let's suppose I copy some text from first browser tab and then I want to paste this text in textbox located in second browser tab. Is it possible to detect in whicxh tab pasted text was copied?  Thank you in aadvance

Comment: You should probably add some context information. E, g. what pages that are, who is operating them, whether the JS has to come from a server, where you need the information etc.

Comment: the only way you may have is developing a chrome extension, by using a script which runs only in another tab of your browser you can't

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: no, this is not possible.

The exception is when you have control over the pages in all tabs and watch for the pasting.

Answer (score 0):

well,I am thinking that you could detect onKeyPress() "ctrl+c" for each element. it only works for key press though not "right-click+copy". next, how do you want to pass it to second browser? you will have to pass the value to server first then to second browser. perhaps with socket.io..

I don't think the second browser can simply paste it.. not with ctrl+v nor with rightclick+paste.. but the copied-value is there, perhaps you might have to provide your own button which will make use of this value